# Unable to crawl full website HTML content using python selenium or request library

Tags: python, selenium, request, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl this site "https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/better-regulation/have-your-say/initiatives/12527-Artificial-intelligence-ethical-and-legal-requirements/feedback_en?p_id=24212003"
but getting only header and few body responses, unable to get full paragraph content and links of pages.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/better-regulation/have-your-say/initiatives/12527-Artificial-intelligence-ethical-and-legal-requirements/feedback_en?p_id=24212003&page=1")
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

So the response has no href and tags that what I need

[What i need from site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhw4J.png)

[result output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6EfZ.png)

Comment: Try not running it headless. You will probably need to pass some headers to run headless.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass some experimental options and scrape the data

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# set chrome options and run headless
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation",
                                                           'disable-component-update',
                                                           'ignore-certificate-errors'])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/better-regulation/have-your-say/initiatives/12527-Artificial-intelligence-ethical-and-legal-requirements/feedback_en?p_id=24212003&page=1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html')
driver.quit()

# find all <a> tags and get the href using dict comprehension
d = {x.text: x['href'] for x in soup.find_all('a', href=True)}
```